# Limiting starting current of a small DC motor

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, dc-motor, robotics

I have 4 12 V DC motors and I am using 11.2 V 2200 mAh LiPo batteries to drive them. They are part of an RF robot which depend on differential drive for turning hence I don't want to compromise on torque.

Actually the problem is my LiPo pack has no current limiter, so when shorted it delivers huge current. Hence, while starting my motor sparks occur at the connecting terminals. Moreover, if the circuit is switched on-off within a short duration, the circuits gets really hot.

Can anyone please suggest a way to control the starting current electronically. Presently my motors are relay controlled.

Comment: Flyback diode ?

Comment: @M.Ferru okay as much as i understand flyback diodes short circuit the circuit during voltag spikes. Shouldn't that will short circuit the battery for that moment and draw huge current? Plz correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: Post a schematic so the pros can see what you currently have. There are thermistor circuits for soft starting and I'd look into MOSFETs for switching rather than pulsing a relay around.

Comment: Maybe use a thermistor for in-rush current.

Comment: The problem is the starting torque.  Motor current is proportional to the torque load, and speed is proportional to motor voltage.  When you apply full voltage on the motor, the motor accelerates your load up to full speed as fast as it can, using up whatever current is available.  This acceleration torque is many times your load torque.  The sparks you are seeing are likely the motor brushes, which are resistive and will get hot when you force a bunch of current.  You must bring up the power slowly using PWM, so relays are not going to get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to correct this bad effect on your circuit is a flyback diode. It's a diode put in parallel of a motor, relay or any inductive load that create a voltage spike when power on (and so a current spike as well).

[image]

In your comment you explain your worry about a short circuit because of that diode. This won't append. The diode conduct the current only when the voltage across the pin are higher than a certain amount. During the voltage spike, this condition is trigger and then the current flow across the diode (the red arrow on the picture). But during the reste of the time, the diode won't conduct.

Comment: A flyback diode across a DC Motor that has to reverse is a non-starter.  If needed, put a reverse current clamp around the driver stage.  The best solution is don't just Turn On The Motors.  Ramp them up at a defined rate.